# Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new in laravel 4.1, I was successfully installed it and do something and I am success. I have experience in Symfony2 all version . For admin in Symfony many third party Bundles like Sonata Admin Bundle available for use. I want same in Laravel.

Any one suggest me best third party admin bundle for Laravel ?

It is available or not ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundles in Laravel are packages, which are compatible with composer.

You can check this package called [Laravel Administrator](http://administrator.frozennode.com/) - [github](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator).

Another: [Laravella](http://laravella.github.io/docs/index.html).

you can add it like:

```
> composer require frozennode/administrator:dev-master
> composer update
```

There should be more if you look for it on packagist.

You can also follow the following, [Grocery CRUD for Laravel](http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/1918-grocery-crud-in-laravel/#entry9746) and the [Official Generator Suggestion](http://laravel.uservoice.com/forums/175973-laravel-4/suggestions/3269209-an-official-admin-generator)

Answer (score 0):

A few packages can be found on [packagist.com](http://packagist.com) or [packalyst.com](http://packalyst.com/packages) just search for the particular bundle or packages you need I looked up sonata and I'm guessing for example you want a shopping cart for an eCommerce site....You can find them at those two links. Plus just approach guys in the community they are always willing to help :)